# Cocoa/Objective-C - Can i somehow see the implementation files?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I believe i can learn thing or two if i can see the implementation files (.m files). Is there any way the i can view NSString.m or NSNumber.m files? and others? If i try to find these files using spotlight, i get nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, most (all?) of the Cocoa library implementations are only distributed in a compiled binary form.  You could disassemble them, but that's probably against the Mac OS X EULA, and it also wouldn't help you understand them at all.

You could take a look at [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/), which is an open-source implementation of Cocoa.  It won't be exactly the same, but at least for the core classes, it will be virtually identical.

Answer (score 6):

Many of the basic cocoa classes, like NSString and NSNumber, are implemented in core foundation and "toll-free bridged" to objective-c classes.  Core foundation is a C (not ObjC) API and the [source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/darwinsource/10.5.5/CF-476.15/) is available as part of the Darwin open-source project.

So, to see how NSString or NSNumber is implemented under the hood, follow the link above and take a look at CFString and CFNumber, respectively (you'll need an Apple developer account, but registration is free).

Answer (score 2):

Also worth looking at the [mySTEP sources](http://www.quantum-step.com/download/sources/mySTEP/).

[This](http://www.quantum-step.com/download/sources/mySTEP/AppKit/Sources/NSMatrix.m) helped me when doing something that subclassed NSMatrix some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess they are already compiled into libraries.

I just did a quick check on my mac and could not find a NSString.m file as well. Are you utilizing Xcode's documentation? I find it has most everything I need.